# 2017 Honda EX-T: Bluetooth malfunctioning when charging on car USB

Tags: honda, civic, bluetooth, power-outlet

When connecting my iPhone 6s to my Civic's USB power, Bluetooth sound speeds up and slows down erratically and I lose the ability to control volume from the steering wheel and Infotainment screen. The moment I disconnect my iPhone from built-in USB power it begins operating normally. Interestingly enough, when I power my phone using this [aftermarket charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VH84L5E) (through the cigarette adapter) I don't experience any of these issues.

My local Honda dealership says they are unable to recreate the issue, but this is not surprising considering the issue pops up on and off without warning. I am convinced there is some sort of interference or power quality issue with the built-in USB ports. I am wondering if anyone else has experienced similar issues and found resolution. I appreciate any guidance anyone can provide.

Comment: Is it a charger or a sync port?

Comment: There is a built-in sync port and charger: the issue occurs on both.